# Designing mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to have the following output.

I would like to have celebrity and their photos in database.
Each celebrity might have more than one photo. Each photo might have more than one celebrity

If a celebrity has more than one photo, I need to get a random photo with celebrity name.

I designed the table like this.

**Celebrity table (Celebrity):**

```
id 
name
```

**Photos table (Photos):**

```
id
photo location
```

**A join table for celebrity and Photos (Celebrity_Photos):**

```
Celebrity id
Photos id
```

But I don't know the right query to get the expected result.
Or i might have designed the table wrongly.

Suggest me the best way to do this.

I know the join query. But i know the basic join query. It gives the info like this.

```
celeb1 photo1
celeb1 photo2
celeb2 photo1
```

But i am looking to acheive

```
 celeb1 photo2
 celeb2 photo1
```

OR

```
celeb1 photo1
celeb2 photo1
```

Answer (score 1):

The photo with the minimum `id` for every celebrity:

```sql
SELECT 
    c.*                        -- columns you need from Celebrity
  , p.*                        -- and Photo tables
FROM 
    celebrity AS c
  LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT celebrity_id
           , MIN(photo_id) AS photo_id
      FROM celebrity_photo
      GROUP BY celebrity_id
    ) AS cp
      ON cp.celebrity_id = c.celebrity_id
  LEFT JOIN 
    photo AS p
      ON p.photo_id = cp.photo_id ;
```

A random photo for every celebrity:

```sql
SELECT 
    c.*                        -- columns you need from Celebrity
  , p.*                        -- and Photo tables
FROM 
    celebrity AS c
  LEFT JOIN 
    photo AS p
      ON p.photo_id = 
        ( SELECT cp.photo_id 
          FROM celebrity_photo AS cp
          WHERE cp.celebrity_id = c.celebrity_id 
          ORDER BY RAND()
              LIMIT 1
        ) ;
```

Comment: I am not getting random photo. It always gives the first photo for that celebrity.

Comment: Edited. Missed taht in first reading.

Comment: I am getting different result everytime. I tried to get name, photo and photo_location. Sometimes, the photo and photo_location is NULL. Sometimes, It lists all the photos of the celebrity. I got more than one result everytime.

Comment: Did you try the (2nd) query as it is? Are there photos for every celebrity? I can't see how you get Nulls if there are.

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

```
[CELEB]  
celeb_id
celeb_name  

[CELEB_PHOTO]  
celeb_photo_id
celeb_id
photo_name
```

Your design is fine, I would start with the below query if there is not a huge amount of records at the mo:

```
SELECT * FROM `CELEB_PHOTO` WHERE `celeb_id` = $celeb_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

You then could get the name of the celeb by query the CELEB table.

Comment: I could be wrong but, I'm not sure the photos table contains a celebrity_id column? Looks like he's using a Join Table?

Comment: I could be wrong also. I got the design like: Photos(photo_id, celeb_id, photo_name).

Comment: Yes i dont have celebrity_id in photos table

Comment: Oh, so you want a PIVOT table for many to many relationship ?

Comment: Should i add celeb id in the photos table as well as in celeb_photos table?

Comment: It depends. If the 2 celebs could have the same photo assigned or not.

Comment: Mahesh... This depends... If you need to have multiple Celebrities "tagged" in one photo, then you NO... If you only have one celeb per photo, then YES.

Comment: In once case, A celeb will have multiple photo. In another case A photo will have multiple celebs.

Comment: Celeb having multiple photos is what I thought

Comment: In which case, your "Join Table" design is best... Where you list Celebs and their Photos as multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT RAND() RND_INDEX, P.PHOTO_ID, P.PHOTO_LOCATION, C.ID, C.NAME
FROM PHOTOS P, CELEBRITY_PHOTOS CP, CELEBRITY C
WHERE P.PHOTO_ID = CP.PHOTO_ID AND CP.ID = DESIRED_CELEBRITY AND CP.ID = C.ID) A ORDER BY RND_INDEX LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumption - you are not taking into consideration photos that have multiple celebrities.
Correction - correct term for what you call a join table is an association table.

I believe your syntax is fine.  The random aspect adds a little bit of complexity and would like need to be done outside the query.

---

Not sure how your tables or code will be set-up but here is the query assuming you are looping through the list of celebrity or have a celebrity id or name (I use $celebrity_id).

```
SELECT PHOTO_T.id 
FROM PHOTO_T, CELEBRITY_PHOTO_A, CELEBRITY_T
WHERE PHOTO_T.id = CELEBRITY_PHOTO_A.photo_id AND CELEBRITY_PHOTO_A.celebrity_id = CELEBRITY_T.id AND CELEBRITY_T.id = $celebrity_id
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;
```

Performance may be slow with the RAND() but it will get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed that you may have several celebrities in 1 photo. If so, your design is just fine.

So, how about this;

```
SELECT Celebrity.name, Photos.photo_location
FROM Celebrity_Photos
INNER JOIN Celebrity on Celebrity.id = Celebrity_Photos.celeb_id
INNER JOIN Photos on Photos.id = Celebrity_Photos.photo_id
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 1
```

I assume you only want 1 photo returning. If not, then simply remove the line;

```
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the join table (association table) as its not 'many to many' add another column to your photos table celeb_id you might want to designate it a foreign key.. and then use 
SELECT * FROM Celebrity c LEFT OUTER JOIN Photos p ON c.celeb_id =p.celeb_id order by rand() limit 1;